# Changing a template using user role and publishing variables

Tags: 7, theming

I've been trying to get the following function to work in Drupal 7, where an unauthenticated user sees a different article template (in this case, node--article2.tpl) than a user that's logged in.  I get no php errors, but the template doesn't change if I'm logged out. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php
   function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   $node = $variables['node'];

   if($node->type === 'article'){
   global $user;
   if($user->uid == 0){
   $variables['template_file'] = 'node__article2';
  }
 }
}
```

Additionally, I'd like the function to look at an article's published state as well.  We're using the custom publishing options module that adds a publishing state of "archived."

So basically unauthenticated users will get a different template that has a publishing state of archived.

Comment: Is page caching enabled? If so, the page is cached in one of the two templates.

Comment: Turned if off and it's still not working.  I'm guessing that it's not finding the template file for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change code

> $variables['template_file'] = 'node__article2';

to

> $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__article2';